# File cannot be deleted

Tags: java, file, input, output

Hi every one i'm programming a server client program which transfers file from client to server some files cannot be accepted and i should delete them after a test but the problem is file.delete() doesn't work for me  cuz  get an error that says file is open i java VM ;

```
    package Serveur;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Serveur {

    private static final int PORT =23456;
    private ServerSocket serverSkt = null;
    private Socket sock = null;
    private FileOutputStream fos = null;
    private boolean isStopped=false;

    private InputStream fis;
    private DataInputStream dis = null;

    private int idUtil=0;
    private String nomFichier = null;
    private int taille = 0; 

    public Serveur() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        try {
            serverSkt = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while(!isStopped){
                sock=serverSkt.accept();

                if(sock.isConnected()) {

                    fis=sock.getInputStream();

                    dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
                    idUtil=dis.readByte();
                    taille=dis.readInt();
                    nomFichier=dis.readUTF();

                    File fichier = new File("C:/Users/muddo/workspace/PFE/fichiers recu/"+nomFichier);
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(fichier);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[taille];

                    int count=0;
                    while((count=dis.read(bytes)) > 0){
                        fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                    }

                        dis.close();
                        fis.close();
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        sock.close();

                        new max_allowed_packet();

                        String ext= fichier.getName().split("\\.")[1];

                        if(ext.equals("csv") || ext.equals("CSV") || ext.equals("Csv")){
                            TestCSV tc = new TestCSV(fichier.getAbsolutePath());
                            if(tc.test()==1){
                                new ChargerFichierCSV(fichier.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                            else{
                                fichier.delete();
                            }
                        }
                        else {  
                            new ChargerFichier(fichier.getAbsolutePath(),idUtil);
                        }

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }


    }

    public void arreterServeur() throws IOException{
        if(dis != null)
            dis.close();

        if(fis != null)
            fis.close();

        if(fos != null)
            fos.close();

        if(!sock.isClosed())
            sock.close();

        if(!serverSkt.isClosed())
            serverSkt.close();

        isStopped=true;
    }

}
```

Comment: the problem is in here else{
                                fichier.delete();
                            }

Comment: Are you sure you close the file whenever you read/write it? You are passing the file name to three classes `TestCSV`, `ChargerFichierCSV` and `ChargerFichier`

Comment: This `dis.close(); fis.close(); fos.flush(); fos.close(); sock.close();` is horrible. Use `try-with-resources`. Your problem is likely related to bad resource handling.

Comment: thanks you @Peter Lawrey  
the problem is i don't close the file in TestCSV class i fixed it 
and now it's working

Answer (score 0):

The server could be running with another user than the user than owns the file. Did you check file permissions??

```
 File fichier = new File("C:/Users/muddo/workspace/PFE/fichiers recu/"+nomFichier);
```

The file is owned by user muddo and the server may be running in another user with less privileges. This seems like a bad idea. You should put shared files in a shared folder. Or give permissions to the server user.